# Returning paths with explorer on WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

In my WPF application I need to save and load files. In order to do so, for now I take the file's name and use that to create a file in the program's folder:

```
SaveFile = Interaction.InputBox("Input the name of the file", "Save", "Stuff") + ".txt";
StreamWriter saver = new StreamWriter(SaveFile);
//then writes stuff in the file
```

I'd like to improve this by using explorer.exe to select a location in which to save, and same thing to load a file, instead of the `InputBox`. I basically need a method which returns me a folder or file path via explorer. I browsed lots of questions on SO but I only found ways to do this via forms, and the last time I tried to use forms in a WPF application I basically screwed Visual Studio up.
So, do you have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify how the user of your application is involved in this and how he is supposed to pick a file and its location if you don't want to go through from what I understand GUI elements?

Comment: Please be aware that standard users do not have permission to “create a file in the program's folder”, and that anything you create there can be deleted if the user repairs or uninstalls your program. You should probably create files in the user's `ApplicationData` folder.

Comment: @Linkø Just to get this straight: You want to incorporate a view of the filesystem into your programm so he can pick a spot in place rather then using a dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want a simple file picker you can you below approach. Otherwise I don't quite understand your requirement with not wanting a form but still give the user a choice of picking folder by using some form of a GUI control.

Try using this from a WPF tutorial => [The OpenFileDialog](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-openfiledialog/):

```
# xml required to set up the example as far as I can tell
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Dialogs.OpenFileDialogSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="OpenFileDialogSample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Button Name="btnOpenFile" Click="btnOpenFile_Click">Open file</Button>
        </WrapPanel>
        <TextBox Name="txtEditor" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The actual C# code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WpfTutorialSamples.Dialogs
{
        public partial class OpenFileDialogSample : Window
        {
                public OpenFileDialogSample()
                {
                        InitializeComponent();
                }

                private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                        if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                                txtEditor.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: @Linkø added another answer showing a different but similar example using a SaveFileDialog from the same WPF tutorial site. Also if you want to roll your own solution how about walking over the filesystem collecting all existing directories up to a certain depth and presenting them to the user in some sort of a tree view gui control. The walking over the filesystem part would probably needed to be made very efficient were you only load the first level nodes and then load the contents of each node when requested by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Well then here is [another example](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-savefiledialog/) from the same site copy and pasted just for saving files with a dialog where you have to use the same XML for replication of a working example I assume:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WpfTutorialSamples.Dialogs
{
        public partial class SaveFileDialogSample : Window
        {
                public SaveFileDialogSample()
                {
                        InitializeComponent();
                }

                private void btnSaveFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                        if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                                File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, txtEditor.Text);
                }
        }
}
```

The dialog looks like this

[image: WPF File Save Dialog]